# Keeping history in Specman prompt

Tags: specman

When I use Specman GUI, I can use back arrow to browse history of the commands given.
Is there a way to get the same functionality when I'm not using GUI (from unix shell for example)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you launch specman, give the -e switch. It will keep history and also auto completion, and other nice editing stuff.
If you use irun, the -e switch is also applicable there, giving the same functionality.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Quoted From [Verification Blog](http://digitalverification.blogspot.de/2009_05_01_archive.html) - the 'show redo' specman command:

"
If you have executed a set of commands and want to see the history of executed commands, you can use "show redo" command.

Specman> show redo
show redo
The redo buffer (default is 'redo 0..') =
0. "restore specman.esv"
1. "load temp.e"
2. "test"
3. "clear screen; restore; reload; test"

Once you know the history of executed command, you can re execute them by issuing "redo" Specman command.

Specman> redo 3 //this will execute command 3 (clear screen; restore; reload; test)
Specman> redo 0..2 //this will execute command 0 to 2 (restore specman.esv, load temp.e, test)

Hope This clarifies things.